# Playframework messages loading issue

Tags: java, playframework

I have a play framework (2.2.3) project which also uses maven. One of the dependencies in my project is org.apache.wss4j.wss4j-ws-security-common-2.1.4.jar. This JAR has a messages folder in classpath. On starting play I get the following error (I am just pasting a few lines here)

```
Oops, cannot start the server.
MainException: class java.lang.NullPointerException(null)
class java.lang.NullPointerException(null)
java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
play.api.i18n.Messages$MessagesParser.parse(Messages.scala:216)
```

If I remove the messages folder from this JAR, play starts normally. I assume that Play tries to load all messages in the classpath and expects them to be files - it breaks because the messages in the WSS4J jar is a folder.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this problem was changing the name to the folder that contains the "wss4j_errors.properties" file.

In code, edit line 42 at src/main/java/org/apache/wss4j/common/crypto/WSS4JResourceBundle.java

Run the tests, compile and try the new jar.

Not the answer I would like, but it works.